# how to create tooltips with arabic text in mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, tooltip, windows

I want to create a simple MFC application which uses the RTL property to display a tooltip with the given Arabic text content for an edit box in the application dialog. 
My code looks like this:

```
HWND CMFCApplicationDlg::CreateToolTip(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR szText){

    hWndTT = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
             WS_POPUP | TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_BALLOON,
             CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
             m_hWnd,
             NULL,
             GetModuleHandle(NULL),
             NULL);

    if(!hWndTT)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (szText == NULL)
    {
        ::DestroyWindow(hWndTT);
        hWndTT = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }

// Set up the tool information. In this case, the "tool" is the entire parent window 
    toolItem.cbSize = sizeof(toolItem);
    toolItem.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_RTLREADING;//Setting RTL flag here
    toolItem.hwnd = m_hWnd;
    toolItem.hinst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    toolItem.lpszText = (wchar_t *)szText;
    toolItem.uId = (UINT_PTR)hWnd;

    ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &toolItem.rect);

    // Associate the tooltip with the tool window    
    LRESULT result = ::SendMessage(hWndTT, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolItem);

   return hWndTT;
}
```

I'm calling this function from OnInitDialog() method this way:

```
CreateToolTip((HWND)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_DUMMY), L".استخدم 2 من المرات في اليوم");
```

Here IDC_EDIT_DUMMY is the ID for the edit box that I am trying to attach the tooltip with. But for some reason, the application doesn't display the tooltip at all. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The MFC has it's own tooltip implementation.  May be it is easier to use this instead of using the plain Win32 tooltips.

You can use [CWnd::EanableTooltips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa23xtsw(v=vs.80).aspx) to activate it. The MSDN doku (see link contains a full sample)

Also code project has a [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28885/CListCtrl-and-Displaying-a-Tooltip) for it.